# Visualizing a heatmap matrix on to an image in OpenCV

Tags: python, keras, heatmap, opencv

I have a (`float32`) heatmap matrix in my Python program like this:

```
[[0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99919313 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  1.         0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]
 [0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705
  0.99782705 0.99782705 0.99782705]]
```

Here is what the heatmap looks like when printed via `matplotlib.pyplot.matshow()`:

[image: Heatmap matrix in its original size]

Now I want to resize that matrix to the size of an image and overlay it as an heatmap on to that image. So first I load the other image and resize the heatmap to the image size:

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
```

After resizing the heatmap matrix becomes this:

[image: Heatmap matrix resized]

Ok, so far everything looks well. Now, based on various resources I found online, I want to transform that heatmap into an `uint8` RGB format, apply the `cv2.COLORMAP_JET` color map, and overlay it on to the original image:

```
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(255 * heatmap), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
superimposed = heatmap * 0.4 + img
```

But that does not seem to work. When I render the heatmap now via `cv2.imshow('Heatmap', heatmap)` it becomes a plain (red) image, it has lost all its "features" from the original heatmap. Therefore also the image I want to lay the heatmap over stays the same as before (i.e. rendering `superimposed` looks exactly as `img`).

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

For ther records, I want to achieve something similar to this:
[Grad-CAM implementation for Keras models](https://github.com/PowerOfCreation/keras-grad-cam)

PS: [Full working example here](https://pastebin.com/YUmPCy1Y)

Comment: Please post a working example, full code including "import" lines so we can reproduce the error without having to guess what your code does.

Comment: So basically with your numbers you get 3 values -> 254.4458 , 254.7942 and 255 then uint8 will convert them to 254 and 255, the colormap works more like a lookup table and will give you almost the same color to it. Now, you can try to use cv2.normalize, this will put the first number to 0 the last one to 255 and the middle one something in between, I can put give you an example if you want

Comment: @L.C. Done, you can find it here: https://pastebin.com/YUmPCy1Y

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is for visualization, you will need to make a bigger separation between the numbers. You have basically 3 numbers and when you scale them (multiply 255) they become basically 2 numbers (254 and 255). When it applies the color, both of the numbers are almost the same, and it is really hard to know which one is which...

Solution:

Create a new scale with the current numbers. You can easily do that with cv2.normalize

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

heatmap = np.array([
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99919313,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,1.00000000,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705],
    [0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705,0.99782705]
])

heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (400,300))
plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
heatmapshow = None
heatmapshow = cv2.normalize(heatmap, heatmapshow, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
heatmapshow = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmapshow, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
cv2.imshow("Heatmap", heatmapshow)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and you get:

[image]

Note: I just put numbers in the resize, since I do not have the sample image.

However, there is one thing to consider here. With this solution the biggest number will be red, independently of how small it is. If you need a new fixed scaling (e.g. 1. is red and 0 is the samllest number) you need to do it manually with something like:

```
newvalue= (maxNew-minNew)/(max-min)*(value-max)+maxNew
```

where `maxNew= 255` and `minNew=0` and max and min will be something you arbitrarily decide (e.g. 0.9978 and 1.0)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Two more questions though: 1) When I apply the heatmap to the original image, then the "gradient" from blue to red (as in your screenshot above) becomes reversed, i.e. now it's from red to blue - but why? 2) Is there an easy way to get rid of that "hard" (horizontal and vertical) border of the area where the heatmap is? Here is an example of an image I created with your change: https://imgur.com/a/dFx1dKb

Comment: @Matthias 2) since it comes from a small image, it will be a little squared around the edges... but one can blur (gaussian for example) the image before blending it. 1) If you are using `superimposed = heatmap * 0.4 + img` as in your post, then it is overflow of uint8... try `superimposed = heatmap * 0.4 + img * 0.6` this will make sure that it stays in bounds

Comment: Just for the records: Both my remaining issues have been solved by replacing the line `heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(255 * heatmap), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)` with `heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(255 * (255 - heatmap)), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)`.